# Set Default Value of Ribbon Checkbox

Tags: experience-editor

I recently discovered a checkbox on the "View" ribbon of the Experience Editor in Sitecore 8.1. This checkbox is used to display validation errors, but it is not checked by default.

[image: Checkbox]

How would I go about enforcing the following:

1. The checkbox is checked by default
2. The checkbox cannot be unchecked (my thinking is to just deny the read/write permission for this button. I just need to make sure it's checked first).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value of the checkbox is set on a per user basis and stored against their profile (which means it is remembered across sessions and browsers/computers).

#### Force Field Validation to be Enabled

To force this checkbox to be enabled, you can set it against the user profile when they log in.

```cs
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggedIn;
using Sitecore.Security.Accounts;
using Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace MyProject.CMS.Pipelines.LoggedIn
{
    public class UserLoggedIn
    {
        public void Process(LoggedInArgs args)
        {
            User user = User.FromName(args.Username, true);
            Assert.IsNotNull(user, "user");
            Registry.SetValue("/Current_User/Page Editor/Capability/FieldsValidation", "on");
            // Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Constants.CheckboxTickedRegistryValue can also be used 
            // as a constant to "on" but you'll need to add a reference to the DLL
        }
    }
}
```

Then patch this into the `loggedin` pipeline:

```xml
<sitecore>
  <processors>
    <loggedin>
      <processor mode="on" type="MyProject.CMS.Pipelines.LoggedIn.UserLoggedIn, MyProject.CMS" /> 
    </loggedin>
  </processors>
</sitecore>
```

#### Force Checkbox to be Disabled

Edit the JS file located in `/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/Commands/EnableFieldsValidation.js` and update the `canExecute` function to return `false`:

```js
canExecute: function (context) {
  return false;
},
```

The checkbox should now appear checked and not changeable. You may have to force refresh the browser cache to pick up the updated JS file.

[image: Field Validation]

Comment: The only thing I'm hesitant to do is modify the JS file. I may end up leaving the checkbox as togglable. As long as when they re-log in it gets checked, I think we're ok.

Comment: @BenLipson Sure, that's understandable. But I wanted to provide you with a full answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Go to core db. Find the:
"/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit/View/Capabilities/Field validation"

Now you can see the "webedit:hidecontrol" is used.

```
<command name="webedit:hidecontrol" type="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.WebEdit.Commands.HideControl, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" />

[Serializable]
public class HideControl : WebEditCommand
{
    // Methods
    public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
    {
    }

    public override CommandState QueryState(CommandContext context) => 
        CommandState.Hidden;
}
```

Add your own command and update the method `QueryState` with `CommandState.Enabled` or `CommandState.Down`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: you beat me with your answer. Love it :).

Comment: I just tried creating a class that extends HideControl and replacing the type of this command with the new one. The checkbox is still unchecked by default, and the validator is not active. I also tried just creating a new  command and assigning it, and it didn't make a difference. I checked ShowConfig.aspx and it does indicate `webedit:hidecontrol` uses my new type.

Comment: You are right. It doesn't work. Sorry. I will try to figure out. I see I missed `StringUtility.EvaluateCheckboxRegistryKeyValue`