# Automatically check some ribbon item

Tags: user-profile, ribbon

[image: I want this check box checked for each user]

Hi, is there is a way to enforce this checkbox value = true each user login ? If enforce not possible, can we globally set check = true for each users?

I found similar question here: [Set Default Value of Ribbon Checkbox](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3090/set-default-value-of-ribbon-checkbox) and make some adjustment since it have different settings and sitecore version as follow

```
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggedIn;
using Sitecore.Security.Accounts;

namespace CustomLogin
{
    public class EnforceEntireTree
    {
        public void Process(LoggedInArgs args)
        {
            User user = User.FromName(args.Username, true);
            Assert.IsNotNull(user, "user");
            user.Profile.SetPropertyValue("/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/View/Entire Tree", "on");
        }
    }
}
```

When it's executed it's throw error: "The settings property '/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/View/Entire Tree' was not found."

UPDATE:

I found proper name for that setting but these code isn't working

```
namespace CustomLogin
{
    public class EnforceEntireTree
    {
        public void Process(LoggedInArgs args)
        {
            User user = User.FromName(args.Username, true);
            Assert.IsNotNull(user, "user");

            string key = "/" + user.Name + "/UserOptions.View.ShowEntireTree";
            user.Profile.Initialize(user.Name, true);
            user.Profile[key] = "true";
            user.Profile.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE #2:
After Andrey Bobrov said, i try to clear cache by using this way:

```
namespace CustomLogin
{
    public class EnforceEntireTree
    {
        public void Process(LoggedInArgs args)
        {
            User user = User.FromName(args.Username, true);
            Assert.IsNotNull(user, "user");

            string key = "/" + user.Name + "/UserOptions.View.ShowEntireTree";
            user.Profile.Initialize(user.Name, true);
            user.Profile[key] = "true";
            user.Profile.Save();

            RegistryCache registryCache = CacheManager.GetRegistryCache(Context.Site);
            registryCache.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Still not working, Do I doing it wrong? If I clear all the cache from sitecore/admin/cache.aspx then the checkbox is checked just by using refresh (F5)

Thank You

Comment: have you cleared the registry cache after executing your code?

Comment: Hi @AndreyBobrov, could you tell me how to clear cache? I trying using above code but not working. Now i'm sure it's about cache since clearing them, then checkbox is checked. Thank You

Comment: @HadiSusanto, I think the cache that is being cleared is not the one which is responsible for the ribbon to take the new values. Check what is the Context.Site returning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have specified in your comment, clearing the cache from the `cache.aspx` page, fixed the issue. The reason why even clearing the cache from the code is not working is because the `Context.Site` is not the correct one.

The `Context.Site` at this point is equal to `login`. You should clear the cache for the `shell`.

```
namespace CustomLogin
{
    public class EnforceEntireTree
    {
        public void Process(LoggedInArgs args)
        {
            User user = User.FromName(args.Username, true);
            Assert.IsNotNull(user, "user");

            string key = "/" + user.Name + "/UserOptions.View.ShowEntireTree";
            user.Profile.Initialize(user.Name, true);
            user.Profile[key] = "true";
            user.Profile.Save();

            // Get the shell site here
            var site = Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext.GetSite("shell");
            RegistryCache registryCache = CacheManager.GetRegistryCache(site );
            registryCache.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this do the trick. As you said Context.Site at that point is `login`

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by setting registry as shown.

[image: PS script to change the registry]

PS script:

```
    --Get the default value
    [Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Registry]::GetBool("/Current_User/UserOptions.View.ShowEntireTree")
    --Set 'true' to the context user        
[Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Registry]::SetBool("/Current_User/UserOptions.View.ShowEntireTree",$true)
```

You can write respective C# code to do the similar stuff after post login or something like that.

Comment: Hi Balaji Kuppuswamy,

I use Registry.SetBool(key, true); but it give me these error: This property cannot be set for anonymous users.

FYI: Those code is running at LoggedIn pipeline

Comment: as mentioned, this should be applicable for CMS users and users should be logged-in or post login event. May i know where are you trying this code,which pipeline ?

Comment: I hook those code by using web.config

<sitecore>
<processors>
<loggedin argsType="Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggedIn.LoggedInArgs">
 <processor mode="on" type="CustomLogin.EnforceEntireTree, CustomLogin" /> 
</loggedin>
</processors>
</sitecore>

Comment: could you make your processor as a last processor i.e. below CleanupUserProfile ?

Comment: It's already bellow CleanupUserProfile,

1. Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggedIn.Ticket, Sitecore.Kernel
2. Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggedIn.CleanupUserProfile, Sitecore.Kernel
3. CustomLogin.EnforceEntireTree, CustomLogin