# Enable view buckets by default?

Tags: content-editor, buckets

Is there a way to enable Buckets view by default for all users?  I can see the Buckets item in the core database, but there doesn't seem to be a field that allows for enabling by default.

Comment: Do you mean to show the hidden tree by default?

Comment: The hidden tree of bucket items, yes.

Comment: Did you try this role "Sitecore Client Bucket Management".  This role gives the user access rights to the /sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Item Buckets item in the Core database.  https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/the-security-roles.html

Comment: I just added this, but that's not what I'm after.  I want to enable the Buckets checkbox by default in the View tab for users.  I can find this item in the Core database, as I mention, but I don't see a straightforward way to set it's value to "on."

Comment: As the view buckets is a checkbox on the ribbon, did you check the solution at https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4934/automatically-check-some-ribbon-item ?

Comment: @Gatogordo, yes, well, one of the solutions on that page showed how to implement this in PSE, so I was able to add this to a script I have that's executed when new users are created and enables that checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From you question I am understanding that you want to enable bucket view by default for all the users, which mean every user can see the bucket items in the content tree as date, month, day folder format(usually). This can achieve by updating the `Sitecore.Buckets.config` file. In this file, there is a section called `dataviews`-

```
<dataviews>
      <dataview name="Master" >
        <patch:attribute name="assembly">Sitecore.Buckets</patch:attribute>
        <patch:attribute name="type">Sitecore.Buckets.Forms.BucketDataView</patch:attribute>
      </dataview>
</dataviews>
```

You need to simply comment out or remove this section. After that Buckets checkbox will not work longer. This section is used to set the view about how items should be rendered in the content tree. You can easily override the existing code as well if you don't like the idea of removing the functionality.